# Remove first element of JSON-Array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I want to remove the first element from a JSON-array. The Json-array has this format:

```
[{"hyperperiod":1200},{"x":"Process0Application1Data1","y": 
["0.00","5.00"],"fillColor":"#008FFB"}, ...]
```

The Result should be:

```
[{"x":"Process0Application1Data1","y": 
["0.00","5.00"],"fillColor":"#008FFB"}, ...]
```

I tried using splice

```
console.log(response.data);
response.data.splice(0, 1);
console.log(response.data);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are many approaches to removing the first element of an array

Comment: You're going to need to edit the question. Include a [mcve] which shows an explanation of what you mean by "does not work".

Comment: I tried this: 
                `response.data.splice(0, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

If you just one to remove the first item from an array, regardless of what type of array it is you can use shift().
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp

In your code that would simply be:

```
response.data.shift();
```